# What does 'linear predictor' mean within the context of a non-linear proportional hazards analysis using Generalized Additive Models (GAM)?

Tags: survival, cox-model, mgcv

I am conducting non-linear survival analysis using Wood's `mgcv` package in `R`. The model produces a linear predictor as the outcome variable when I produce a chart (as per the below code). What does linear predcitor actually mean? How do I interpret it?

```
df <- structure(list(SurvYear =c(3L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 
8L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 
7L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
9L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 
6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 
4L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
9L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 
9L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 
9L, 5L, 4L), Gender = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L), Age = c(63L, 66L, 34L, 43L, 63L, 21L, 24L, 44L, 52L, 
59L, 27L, 32L, 30L, 20L, 56L, 55L, 35L, 26L, 53L, 43L, 39L, 19L, 
34L, 28L, 19L, 24L, 50L, 22L, 58L, 24L, 50L, 25L, 37L, 30L, 51L, 
69L, 23L, 49L, 22L, 46L, 58L, 31L, 23L, 53L, 59L, 25L, 38L, 44L, 
34L, 49L, 19L, 39L, 24L, 51L, 29L, 27L, 48L, 77L, 22L, 43L, 59L, 
49L, 60L, 51L, 49L, 47L, 50L, 44L, 41L, 44L, 50L, 42L, 46L, 54L, 
35L, 21L, 26L, 26L, 40L, 21L, 48L, 49L, 20L, 20L, 32L, 37L, 22L, 
36L, 46L, 28L, 39L, 35L, 51L, 39L, 49L, 57L, 46L, 18L, 52L, 47L, 
27L, 32L, 23L, 43L, 42L, 57L, 22L, 40L, 19L, 58L, 71L, 55L, 42L, 
20L, 51L, 21L, 20L, 61L, 36L, 54L, 19L, 35L, 38L, 41L, 34L, 22L, 
41L, 42L, 56L, 50L, 53L, 53L, 48L, 22L, 59L, 27L, 28L, 32L, 37L, 
68L, 24L, 26L, 61L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 50L, 62L, 61L, 29L, 18L, 40L, 
67L, 43L, 25L, 43L, 22L, 56L, 47L, 41L, 40L, 43L, 27L, 37L, 61L, 
35L, 23L, 54L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 45L, 49L, 63L, 49L, 44L, 44L, 23L, 
37L, 58L, 61L, 25L, 18L, 59L, 25L, 51L, 40L, 27L, 42L, 22L, 38L, 
22L, 45L, 33L, 32L, 36L, 53L, 52L, 19L, 45L, 53L, 27L, 65L, 25L, 
53L, 57L, 29L, 23L, 62L, 36L, 56L, 59L, 41L, 61L, 44L, 24L, 21L, 
38L, 29L, 55L, 33L, 18L, 21L, 19L, 65L, 24L, 59L, 34L, 25L, 45L, 
48L, 18L, 41L, 61L, 32L, 37L, 21L, 20L, 57L, 25L, 65L, 50L, 61L, 
32L, 27L, 19L, 50L, 63L, 19L, 45L, 20L, 36L, 20L, 19L, 53L, 39L, 
50L, 20L, 24L, 57L, 28L, 21L, 39L, 49L, 21L, 20L, 39L, 20L, 44L, 
19L, 39L, 53L, 29L, 60L, 43L, 21L, 23L, 30L, 42L, 42L, 51L, 35L, 
50L, 51L, 56L, 52L, 22L, 36L, 56L, 28L, 57L, 20L, 47L, 48L, 65L, 
71L, 21L, 70L, 23L, 63L), Highest_Educationmx = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
5L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L), Censor = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -300L))

library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)

#Run the model
Model1 <- gam(SurvYear~
                (Gender)+
                s(Age, k=50)+  
                s(Highest_Educationmx, k=7),
              weights=Censor, data=df, gamma=1.5, family=cox.ph())
summary(Model1)

#Build a perspective chart
vis.gam(Model1, view=c("Age","Highest_Educationmx"),
        plot.type="persp", color="gray", se=-1, theta=45, phi=25,
        xlab="Age", ylab= "Highest Education",
        ticktype="detailed", zlim=c(-5.00, 2.00))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a [Generalized Additive Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model) (GAM) allows for non-linear relationships of an *original* set of predictors to outcome, the model is still linear in the coefficients of the basis functions used for the non-linear portions of the model. So the [linear predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictor_function) is what it always is: the sum of products of predictors times associated regression coefficients. It's just that with a GAM the relationship between the basis functions used as "predictors" in the model and the original set of predictors isn't immediately obvious.

For a Cox model, the linear predictor is related to the log-hazard of outcome, versus the baseline condition.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense.